# How can I create a foldable ribbon?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to program a foldable ribbon. So I've this code here:

```css
.ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}

.ribbon-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}

.ribbon.base {
  background: #666666;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 5px solid #666666;
}

.ribbon.light {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  color: #2c3e50;
  border-right: 5px solid #dde4e6;
}

.ribbon.dark {
  background: #131313;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 5px solid #464646;
}

.ribbon.base-alt {
  background: #9cd70e;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 5px solid #c6f457;
}

.ribbon.red {
  background: #e91b23;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 5px solid #f2787d;
}

.ribbon.orange {
  background: #ff8a3c;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 5px solid #ffc7a2;
}

.ribbon.yellow {
  background: #ffd800;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 5px solid #ffe866;
}

.ribbon:before,
.ribbon:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -9px;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}

.ribbon:before {
  top: 0;
}

.ribbon:after {
  bottom: 0;
}

.ribbon.base:before {
  border-top: 27px solid #666666;
}

.ribbon.base:after {
  border-bottom: 27px solid #666666;
}

.ribbon.light:before {
  border-top: 27px solid #ecf0f1;
}

.ribbon.light:after {
  border-bottom: 27px solid #ecf0f1;
}

.ribbon.dark:before {
  border-top: 27px solid #131313;
}

.ribbon.dark:after {
  border-bottom: 27px solid #131313;
}

.ribbon.base-alt:before {
  border-top: 27px solid #9cd70e;
}

.ribbon.base-alt:after {
  border-bottom: 27px solid #9cd70e;
}

.ribbon.red:before {
  border-top: 27px solid #e91b23;
}

.ribbon.red:after {
  border-bottom: 27px solid #e91b23;
}

.ribbon.orange:before {
  border-top: 27px solid #ff8a3c;
}

.ribbon.orange:after {
  border-bottom: 27px solid #ff8a3c;
}

.ribbon.yellow:before {
  border-top: 27px solid #ffd800;
}

.ribbon.yellow:after {
  border-bottom: 27px solid #ffd800;
}

.ribbon span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="container bootstrap snippet">
  <div class="row mb-20">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="ribbon-content">
        <div class="ribbon base"><span>New: I'm a new feature.</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I need to change it somehow to only show the word `New`. When I hover now the word, the ribbon should fold out to the left until the whole text is visible. When I leave the ribbon now, it should fold back in.

Is this possible with a smooth animation? I need to be sure the the whole ribbon get's fold out because the length of the text can be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simplify your code like below then it should be easy to manage using a width animation:

```css
.ribbon {
  --c:red;   /* Color */
  --s:20px; /* Size */
  --p:10px; /* padding*/
  
  padding:var(--p);
  border-left:calc(var(--s)/2) solid transparent;
  display:inline-block;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top    right,transparent 48%,var(--c) 50%) border-box,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 48%,var(--c) 50%) border-box,
    var(--c) padding-box;
  background-size:var(--s) 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  color:#fff;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

.ribbon > span {
  display:inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
  max-width:0px;
  transition:0.3s all;
  overflow:hidden;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
.ribbon:hover > span {
  display:inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
  max-width:180px;
  transition:1s all;
}

body {
 text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="ribbon">
  NEW:<span> Some text here</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="ribbon" style="--c:blue;--s:25px">
  NEW: <span>Some long long  text here</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="ribbon" style="--c:purple;--s:45px;--p:15px">
  NEW: <span>text</span>
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: Can I add a box shaddow to the ribbon so that the shaddow don't goes out of the inner corner?     box-shadow: 0 0.12rem 0.4rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);

Comment: @Mr.Jo try `filter:drop-shadow(0 0.12rem 0.4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)))`

Comment: There is no error in the browser but this part of css is grayed out and seems to be not working.

Comment: @Mr.Jo sorry there is an extra space at the end .. you need only two

Comment: Oh, I could have seen this by myself

Comment: Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not looking for a curl effect, I think this might help you out.

```css
.ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  transform: translate3d(145px, 0, 0);
  transition: transform 300ms;
}

.ribbon-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ribbon-content:hover .ribbon {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.ribbon.base {
  background: #666666;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 5px solid #666666;
}

.ribbon.light {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  color: #2c3e50;
  border-right: 5px solid #dde4e6;
}

.ribbon.dark {
  background: #131313;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 5px solid #464646;
}

.ribbon.base-alt {
  background: #9cd70e;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 5px solid #c6f457;
}

.ribbon.red {
  background: #e91b23;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 5px solid #f2787d;
}

.ribbon.orange {
  background: #ff8a3c;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 5px solid #ffc7a2;
}

.ribbon.yellow {
  background: #ffd800;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 5px solid #ffe866;
}

.ribbon:before,
.ribbon:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -9px;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}

.ribbon:before {
  top: 0;
}

.ribbon:after {
  bottom: 0;
}

.ribbon.base:before {
  border-top: 27px solid #666666;
}

.ribbon.base:after {
  border-bottom: 27px solid #666666;
}

.ribbon.light:before {
  border-top: 27px solid #ecf0f1;
}

.ribbon.light:after {
  border-bottom: 27px solid #ecf0f1;
}

.ribbon.dark:before {
  border-top: 27px solid #131313;
}

.ribbon.dark:after {
  border-bottom: 27px solid #131313;
}

.ribbon.base-alt:before {
  border-top: 27px solid #9cd70e;
}

.ribbon.base-alt:after {
  border-bottom: 27px solid #9cd70e;
}

.ribbon.red:before {
  border-top: 27px solid #e91b23;
}

.ribbon.red:after {
  border-bottom: 27px solid #e91b23;
}

.ribbon.orange:before {
  border-top: 27px solid #ff8a3c;
}

.ribbon.orange:after {
  border-bottom: 27px solid #ff8a3c;
}

.ribbon.yellow:before {
  border-top: 27px solid #ffd800;
}

.ribbon.yellow:after {
  border-bottom: 27px solid #ffd800;
}

.ribbon span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="container bootstrap snippet">
  <div class="row mb-20">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="ribbon-content">
        <div class="ribbon base"><span>New: I'm a new feature.</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with your soulution is that when the text is longer thank the predefined one or different, the new is too much to the left or to the right.

Answer (score 0):

You could get this easily done by wrapping the text after 'new' inside a div and do some changes to your css:

- Wrap ': I'm a new feature.' inside `<div class="infotext"></div>`
- Change display for `.ribbon span` from `block` to flex
- Add css rules for your new class .Infotext like in the example below

The hover gets animated by the css-property `transition`. With `all` we tell it to animate everything and to do it in `0.5s`.

> To learn mor about `transition` take a look at [this
>   documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

The text gets hidden by `max-witdh: 0;` and gets displayed by `max-width: 300px`.

> I'm using max-width instead of width, becaus with that we dont have to
>   know the width of each ribbons infotext. To learn more about `max-width` [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)

---

*Feel free to ask me per comment, if anything is unclear.*

---

**Working example:**

```css
.ribbon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
    padding: 15px;
}
.ribbon-content{
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid #DDD;    
}
.ribbon.base {
    background: #666666;
    color: #fff;
    border-right: 5px solid #666666;
}
.ribbon.light {
    background: #ecf0f1;
    color: #2c3e50;
    border-right: 5px solid #dde4e6;
}
.ribbon.dark {
    background: #131313;
    color: #fff;
    border-right: 5px solid #464646;
}
.ribbon.base-alt {
    background: #9cd70e;
    color: #fff;
    border-right: 5px solid #c6f457;
}
.ribbon.red {
    background: #e91b23;
    color: #fff;
    border-right: 5px solid #f2787d;
}
.ribbon.orange {
    background: #ff8a3c;
    color: #fff;
    border-right: 5px solid #ffc7a2;
}
.ribbon.yellow {
    background: #ffd800;
    color: #fff;
    border-right: 5px solid #ffe866;
}
.ribbon:before, .ribbon:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -9px;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
.ribbon:before {
    top: 0;
}
.ribbon:after {
    bottom: 0;
}
.ribbon.base:before {
    border-top: 27px solid #666666;
}
.ribbon.base:after {
    border-bottom: 27px solid #666666;
}
.ribbon.light:before {
    border-top: 27px solid #ecf0f1;
}
.ribbon.light:after {
    border-bottom: 27px solid #ecf0f1;
}
.ribbon.dark:before {
    border-top: 27px solid #131313;
}
.ribbon.dark:after {
    border-bottom: 27px solid #131313;
}
.ribbon.base-alt:before {
    border-top: 27px solid #9cd70e;
}
.ribbon.base-alt:after {
    border-bottom: 27px solid #9cd70e;
}
.ribbon.red:before {
    border-top: 27px solid #e91b23;
}
.ribbon.red:after {
    border-bottom: 27px solid #e91b23;
}
.ribbon.orange:before {
    border-top: 27px solid #ff8a3c;
}
.ribbon.orange:after {
    border-bottom: 27px solid #ff8a3c;
}
.ribbon.yellow:before {
    border-top: 27px solid #ffd800;
}
.ribbon.yellow:after {
    border-bottom: 27px solid #ffd800;
}

.ribbon span {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.ribbon .infotext {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  max-width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ribbon:hover .infotext {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container bootstrap snippet">
    <div class="row mb-20">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="ribbon-content">
                <div class="ribbon base"><span>New<div class="infotext">: I'm a new feature.</div></span></div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try JqueryUI for the animation effect. I havn't tested it, but probably this will give you the idea.

```
<div class="container bootstrap snippet">
    <div class="row mb-20">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="ribbon-content">
                <div class="ribbon base"><span class='newSpn'>New:</span><span class='content'> I'm a new feature.</span></div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>

$('.newSpn').mouseenter(function(){
   $('.content').show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
}).mouseleave(function(){
   $('.content').hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
});
```

It requires the jQuery-ui library. See http://www.jqueryui.com